# How to make UIWebview url address area progressbar

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiprogressbar

I am creating a web-browser app.

My Question here is how to add `UIProgressbar` bar in `UIWebView`'s address area

like to safari app.

[image]

Comment: already existing: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=browser
at least you can review how it's done

Comment: @Injectios thinks, i search it

Comment: @Terran can you please share that direct link with us so that i can use this feature in my app also. this is really a great idea to show loading like this for webview